# How to refresh a list in Angular based on user input

Tags: angular, primeng

Basically I'm trying to create a simple search bar with static data. I tried multiple approaches. I'm using primeng's ListBox to display the list of searched items. Here are some bits and pieces of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search..."
  [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
  (keyup)="refreshSearchList(searchValue)"
  #myInput
/>

<p-listbox
  [options]="searchList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit"
  optionLabel="name"
></p-listbox>
```

**TS**

```
  interface Fruit {
    name: string;
    code: number;
  }

  searchList: Fruit[] = [
    { name: 'Apple', code: 1 },
    { name: 'Banana', code: 2 },
    { name: 'Guavava', code: 3 },
    { name: 'Kiwi', code: 4 },
    { name: 'Blueberry', code: 5 },
    { name: 'Pine Apple', code: 6 },
    { name: 'Strawberry', code: 7 },
  ];

  sendEntireList(): Fruit[] {
    return this.searchList;
  }
```

my main logic to filter out by term is this:

```
  filterByKey(searchWhat: string) {
    let wholeList = this.sendEntireList();
    wholeList.map((item: any) => {
      if (item.name.includes(searchWhat)) {
        this.list.push(item);
      }
    });
    return this.list;
  }
```

I also tried to achieve this using RxJs:

```
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let term = fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'keyup');
    term
      .pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        // console.log(res);
        // call refreshSearchList here
      });
  }
```

Somewhere i'm missing something important. My code is not working at all. Here is the complete [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-gfbnrx). Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`ngModelChange`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) output like below

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..."
  [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ngModelChange)="onQueryChange()"
/>

<p-listbox [options]="filteredList" optionLabel="name"></p-listbox>
```

And in your TypeScript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface Fruit {
  name: string;
  code: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-box',
  templateUrl: './search-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-box.component.css'],
})
export class SearchBoxComponent {
  searchList: Fruit[] = [
    { name: 'Apple', code: 1 },
    { name: 'Banana', code: 2 },
    { name: 'Guavava', code: 3 },
    { name: 'Kiwi', code: 4 },
    { name: 'Blueberry', code: 5 },
    { name: 'Pine Apple', code: 6 },
    { name: 'Strawberry', code: 7 },
  ];

  filteredList = this.searchList;

  searchValue = '';

  onQueryChange() {
    this.filteredList = this.searchList.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
}
```

StackBlitz working version

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-jd25su

Comment: can i use `(onChange)` instead of `ngModelChange()` ?

Comment: I guess you mean `change` event, right?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event